# How to monitor Ajax calls?

Tags: json, jquery

I have a html page in which there are multiple JQuery Ajax calls like get,post etc. Now i want to monitor the ajax calls which call is in which state and i don't want to use the "success", "error" methods. Is there any other way to monitor all Ajax calls with in the page.

Regards,
Ehsan

Comment: Any reasonable browser nowadays has a debugger built in, which also tracks all web requests including AJAX calls.

Comment: Yes i know couple of debuggers like Fiddler. but i want to check the status of every ajax call to server with in the html page.

Comment: A debugger will log every ajax call. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can configured a success for all ajax calls globally.

```
$.ajaxComplete(function() {
    alert('it worked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store ajax request in variable

```
var req1 = $.ajax({});
```

Also you may need this

```
var my_var;

$.ajax({
beforeSend:function(x){my_var=x;}

});
```